# Vuex store, why adding to array overwrites all values in store with last entry?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I am using vuex-typescript. This is one store module:

```
import { getStoreAccessors } from "vuex-typescript";
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "../../store";
import { ActionContext } from "vuex";
class State {
  history: Array<object>;
}

const state: State = {
  history: [],
};

export const history_ = {
  namespaced: true,
  getters: {

    history: (state: State) => {

      return state.history;
    },

  },
  mutations: {

    addToHistory (state: State, someob: any) {

      state.history.push(someob);

    },

    resetState: (s: State) => {
      const initial = state;
      Object.keys(initial).forEach(key => { s[key] = initial[key]; });
    },
  },

  actions: {
    addToHistory(context: ActionContext<State, any>, someob: any) {
      commitAddToHistory(store, someob);
    }

  }

const { commit, read, dispatch } =
  getStoreAccessors<State, any>("history_");
const mutations = history_.mutations;
const getters = history_.getters;
const actions = history_.actions;

export const commitResetState = commit(mutations.resetState);
export const commitAddToHistory = commit(mutations.addToHistory);
export const getHistory = read(getters.history);
export const dispatchAddToSearchHistory = dispatch(actions.addToHistory);
```

Now if if call `dispatchAddToSearchHistory` or `commitAddToHistory` it is always the same all values get overwritten. For example if I add one element to store then it looks like this:

```
store = [
  {
    a: 1
  }
]
```

now when I add another object `{b: 2}` store becomes

```
store = [
  {
    b: 2
  },
  {
    b: 2
  }
]
```

All values are owerwritten by last entry. For example if I try to add `{c:3}` then store looks like (and so on):

```
store = [
  {
    c: 3
  },
  {
    c: 3
  },
  {
    c: 3
  }
]
```

Comment: The only thing that I see that is strange is that you define `state` off of the `history_` Object and it looks like it is never added as a property of `history_`.  In the [small example on the GitHub](https://github.com/istrib/vuex-typescript#example), `state` is defined **on** the `basket` store Object.  Could you try defining it on the Object proper and see if that changes anything?

Comment: i literally copy paste that logic and still getting same thing. well this is frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

....hmmmm, well, I think you may be sending the same object, every time

please try this mutation

```
addToHistory (state: State, someob: any) {
  state.history.push({...someob});
},
```

or this action

```
addToHistory(context: ActionContext<State, any>, someob: any) {
  commitAddToHistory(store, {...someob});
}
```

this, using the spread operator, clones the object. That way every item you add will be new object.

Comment: this is working, what the hack did you do? what this {...someob} means?

Comment: it is called a spread operator, it's an es6 feature; Similar to `Object.assign(...)` they create a copy of an object, this makes sure that you have a new object being added, instead of a new instance of the same object