# How to apply spread operator to store commit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

related to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063795/live-data-destroying-initial-state-data-in-vue)

I am commiting data to a store with

```
const PERFORMANCE_COMMIT = (state, payload) => {
state.Performance[payload.line] = payload.val;
}
```

Every time I do it deletes the values of other items within the store
Store snippit:

```
  Performance: {
    TotalPartTarget: 0,
    TotalPartCount: 0,
    Difference: 0,
    OEE: 0,
    OEETarget: 100,
    "Sinto 1" :{
      PartTarget: 0,
      PartCount: 0,
      NGPartCount: 0,
      OEE: 0,
      FaultTime: 0,
      OnHeatTime: 0,
      CycleTimeMan: 0,
      CycleTimeMach: 0,
      CollectManTimer: 0,
      CollectMachTimer: 0,
      AvgManTime: 0,
      AvgMachTime: 0,
      ManTargetSeconds: 0,
      MachTargetSeconds: 0
    },
```

I've done some research and looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309190/vuex-store-why-adding-to-array-overwrites-all-values-in-store-with-last-entry) I should use the spread operator to ensure I'm not obliterating everything else in the store but I cannot figure out correct usage in my use case.

Ultimately I think my current code is making the "Performance // Sinto 1 object empty except for what I send in, when what I need it to do is modify the element that I have initialised and leave the others alone.

Comment: I think that the use of the spread syntax here is being used as a way of creating a shallow object copy, which is a big topic. Have you tried using `let newObj = Object.assign({}, doNotTouchObj);` ? That might work for your case, but there is too little code in your post to tell.

Comment: I've changed my first code snippet to include the line instead of the comment. I think what I can do although it feels dirty is read the original array, modify it, then pass the whole array back.

Comment: What array, there is none in your example.

Comment: What are the possible values of `payload.val` and `state.Performance[payload.line]`?

Comment: If you're using an array you can make a shallow copy (so the original won't get modified) using `let newArr = Array.from(oldArr);`

Comment: I'm still new at this, while I thought I was working with arrays I was actually working with objects.  by merging them like I have done in my answer post I've gotten what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I've done a dirty fix, including it here for discussion:

```
const PERFORMANCE_COMMIT = (state, payload) => {
let newArray = state.Performance[payload.line]
let mergedArray = {...newArray, ...payload.val}
state.Performance[payload.line] = mergedArray;
state.Performance[payload.line] = payload.val;
```

my combining the two objects I get what I want.

Comment: The last line overwrites the item written in the penultimate line. Overall you can probably reduce most of this to one line: `state.Performance[payload.line] = { ...state.Performance[payload.line], ...payload.val };`